# Filter dhtmlxCombo and readonly mode

Tags: readonly, dhtmlx

I want make the dhtmlxCombo readonly but enable filtering. Currently if we make the combo readonly

```
combo.readonly(true);
```

it does not allow filtering.
The issue is, when we type something in the combo to filter and there is no matching values, it will send the new value. I don’t want to send the new value, but only the ones from the combo list.

Answer (score 0):

The readonly() method means that you can't enter the text in input. This fact causes impossibility to enter letters for filtration. The inability of typing and a filtration - are two mutually exclusive features.

Answer (score 0):

you have to validate before sending it to server side.if you store the combo as key value pairs,while validation it will not allow to submit the form.